# Getting downvotes because you don't have enough Rep to comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation, not-an-answer, privileges

I have often gotten downvotes on some of my answers even though the people who do downvote admit that my posts are useful, but they should be a comment instead of an answer. Is there a way this can be prevented or do users with high reputation simply ignore the fact because they don't have the same problem?
Or rather should someone who will be in my shoes in the future have to indicate that they don't have enough reputation to comment on any post?

Comment: Why do you think we have the restriction in the first place? If we allowed anyone to just circumvent it by posting comments as answers, wouldn't that defeat the point entirely?

Comment: What I am talking about is those users who do not have enough reputation to actually comment? isn't stackoverflow about sharing your knowledge? I do understand the appropriateness of the locations where to put it, but if you don't have any rights, should you be downvoted only because of that?
Not everyone with 1 rep is a newbie in their field.

Comment: You start off with exactly two privileges: asking questions, and answering questions. You can start by sharing your knowledge through those two avenues - if anything, I'd say those were *more effective* ways of sharing your knowledge than mere comments. If we simply allowed anyone to post answers just because they didn't have commenting privileges, we might as well just remove the restriction entirely so that people could post comments in the right places, thereby keeping things clean and organized.

Comment: Should one be downvoted? That's debatable. I would remove the answer outright without voting on it, but only because I'm a moderator. On the other hand, there is only so much a regular user can do.

Comment: Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 30):

> Is there a way this can be prevented

Yes - don't post comments as answers. Rather than skirting round the restriction, accept it as an intentional restriction - if you want to comment, earn that right with reputation.

You talk about "users with high reputation" - but it only takes 50 rep to comment. That's not a very high bar at all.

Comment: 50 rep might not be much, but if you are just starting its a huge hurdle, also i understand that not every question can have an answer but rather ask the OP to look deeper at why the got an error, etc.
At the same time, as a means to put a threshold on who actually comments acts as a way to filter out possible low quality comments, the same way exams do, not everyone who fails an exam is dumb. but generally that's a system that has been implemented to prevent that.
That much I do understand, what I am asking is that is there a way to indicate that you don't have rights to comment?

Comment: No - in fact, doing so will only make things worse for you. And although not every question is immediately answerable - that's why we have people closing them - that's not to say there's a shortage of questions that *are* answerable either.

Comment: @mahlatse: That can already be inferred by your rep. But the solution isn't to say "I know I'm basically trying to break the rules" - it's to *not break the rules*.

Comment: @mahlatse You have > 50 rep, you can comment.

Comment: @Infinite Recursion: Maybe he's referring to previous answers that were posted when he didn't have enough rep.